# KineticJS on drag event for stage

Tags: kineticjs, drag

I'm searching a event like:

```
stage.on('drag',function(){
  // do something
});
```

Only I can search in Internet is events *dragstart* and *dragend*. Something like that is exist in KineticJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the event `dragmove`?

If so:

```
stage.on('dragmove',function(){
  // do something
});
```